# Why are there vines over the entrance to Bthardamz?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am looking for Atherium shards for the key to the Atherium forge.

I went to Bthardamz to search for them. After you go down the stairs, where you can pull a lever and the spinning blades come out, I pulled the one for the bars to open the next room. But when I get to the next door there are vines covering the door. What do I do?

Answer (score 6):

[Bthardamz](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Bthardamz) is only accessible during the Quest [The Only Cure](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Only_Cure), which starts at the Shrine to Peryite. From the first linked article:

> Bthardamz is an ancient Dwemer ruin located in The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim. It is the largest ruin in the game. The entire ruin is inaccessible unless the quest The Only Cure has been started.

Answer (score -1):

That location is not involved in finding the Atherium Shards, so dont worry. Check the journal that Katria prompts you to pick up at the first Atherium Shard location. It has a rough map of Skyrim showing the location of each Shard.

Comment: The question seems to be asking about how to get around in Bthardamz rather than where exactly to find Atherium Shards.